# Click a button with XPath using an id from the same row

Tags: php, selenium, testing, xpath, phpunit

Im currently testing using PHPUnit and i need to create and delete the same things. So i create something called test, i want to be able to find it and delete it. I have multiple Delete buttons on the page, and it works by doing something like this -

```
    $this->click("xpath=(//img[@title='Delete'])[11]");
```

but by choosing [11] for example, it is only using the delete button from row 11. And if Test isnt Row 11 for example, i will delete something i do not wish to delete.

I wish to try and delete a specific row by finding a row with a certain id attached to it.

The row may have the words "Test" followed by more information within columns. Then a delete button at the end titled 'Delete'. I wish to find the row with the id or words 'Test' and then find and use the 'Delete' title on that row.

Any help?

EDIT -Example image of a row. I would like to grab the first text, and then use the very last button on the right titled 'Delete'

https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4BNE.png

SECOND EDIT - This is the whole table, it contains all of the rows and within the rows it contains the td's (Obviously, as you'd know). 
This is where ill find the text im trying to find. This tr would count as the 4th of 6.

This shows the td containing delete, a td containing 'Test Profile' and the whole table itself.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9GK3.png

TL;DR Essentially, im trying to do, Where td contains 'Test', use 'Delete' from the same row.

Comment: Please show a sample of a row that you want to find. We could ask questions back and forth about the details, but an example is worth a thousand words.

Comment: Edited with an Image of two rows that would be there. Row one would be --'Delete'])[1] and row 2 would be [2]

But i wish to use the text in the row to determine which delete i use. I cannot do it by id either, as id's are generated for each create and are never the same.

Comment: OK that helps, but more helpful would be to post the HTML of the rows. It looks like these are table rows `<tr>` and you want to select those that contain `Test` in either the first `<td>` element, or in an ID attribute of the `<tr>` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very clear but I'll try to guess from your comments.

Forget about rows, but let's find all the `td` with "Test" (or some text  you want in it)

```
descendant::td[contains(.,'Test')]/
```

and from here select the following-sibling `td` that contains a delete image

```
following-sibling::td//img[@title='Delete']
```

now you have the set of images nodes to click on, for each row.

Of course, if your function

```
$this->click("xpath=.....");
```

accepts only one node at the time, one possibility is to put the parenthesis and select always the first node (assuming that your test will delete it)

```
(descendant::td[contains(.,'Test')]/following-sibling::td//img[@title='Delete'])[1]
```

Even if the node is deleted when you click on it, in the next test this expression will always match, until there is any node left on the page

This is similar (not perfectly the same) to having a for loop ?

```
buttons = "xpath=....."

for each b in buttons do {

$this->click(b);
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: This is perfect thank you very much, it worked like a charm.

I didnt use the loop as the first line of code worked.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to find the first row that contains Test in the first `<td>` element, or that has an id attribute of "Test" on the `<tr>` element; and you want to click the Delete img element from that row, you could try

```
$this->click("xpath=(//tr[@id='Test' or contains(td[1], 'Test')]//img[@title='Delete'])[1]");
```

But this is somewhat guesswork, since I can't see the HTML you're working with.

Since it looks like 'Test' could be in all-caps or in mixed-case, you may have to build in some case-insensitivity:

```
$this->click("xpath=(//tr[@id='Test' or
  contains(translate(td[1], 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'),
             'TEST')]//img[@title='Delete'])[1]");
```

Yes it's kludgy, but AFAIK PHP only supports XPath 1.0.

Comment: With the code you've provided the 'Delete'])[1] works in the sense that the [1] is picking the <tr> which wont work for me as the rows will be alphabetical, and once something is deleted another will assume the roll of [1].

This is the reason i need to try select by the name inside of the <td>. The <td> is found within an un-named <tr> which is within a <tbody>.

Ill will try add some simple HTML code to the question above, 

Thanks again.